# CSS max-width text sizing issues

Tags: html, css, sass, alignment

I have an accordion style header which I need to align an absolute positioned icon next too. I can easily do this currently by setting the icon to absolute and the H3 title to relative and aligning it negative to the right.

The issue I am having is that my text has a max-width on mobile to stop it hitting the button aligned to the right leaving room for the icon. When the text hits this icon it spans 2 lines but the max-wisth means that my icon is no longer aligned with the text. Does anyone know any workarounds for this to align it neatly to the text

#### Example

See the image below for how the multiline header spans 2 lines and the max width puts the icon at the very end

[image]

annotated image

[image]

#### Code

CSS

```
h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
    color: #211850 !important;
    font-size: 17px !important;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    max-width: calc(50% - 19px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.fa-question-circle-o {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -25px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
 <h3>
    {{ agreement.sectionName }}
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" (click)="openModal(agreement.sectionName, agreement.infoContent)"></i>
</h3>
```

Comment: post your html code too

Comment: Where exactly do you want that icon to align? Top or bottom? It is currently aligned to the very center of the division.

Comment: Also, please add your code in a working jsfiddle so we can provide better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of handling this is to use `width: min-content` which will set the width to the minimum required to display all the content.

(Note: in the snippet, I had to add quite a bit of HTML and CSS to make it look like your screenshots; it would have been better if you'd have posted a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

```css
section {
  width: 290px;
  height: 61px;
  position: relative;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin: .5em;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 800 !important;
  color: #211850 !important;
  font-size: 17px !important;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  max-width: calc(50% - 19px);
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* debug */
  outline: 2px solid red;
  /* solution */
  width: min-intrinsic;         /* old Safari */
  width: -moz-min-content;      /* Firefox */
  width: -webkit-min-content;   /* old Chrome */
  width: min-content;           /* modern browsers */
}

.fa-question-circle-o {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 2px;
}

/* emulate FA */
.fa-question-circle-o::after {
  font-style: normal;
  content: '?';
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color:#969696;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>
    Test
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" (click)="openModal(agreement.sectionName, agreement.infoContent)"></i>
  </h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h3>
    Testing
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" (click)="openModal(agreement.sectionName, agreement.infoContent)"></i>
  </h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h3>
    Testing multiline
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" (click)="openModal(agreement.sectionName, agreement.infoContent)"></i>
  </h3>
</section>
```

Warnings:

- This doesn't work in IE and Edge. If you need to support those, this solution is out
- The width of the h3 will become the minimum required to display all the content; which may not be what you want. Change the content of the first one from "Test" to "X Y Z" to see what I mean.

Comment: Will make sure to provide a better example next time, thanks for the help!